# In Mac os how to use bundle jre for my app, can we use the install4j bundle jre?

Tags: macos, install4j

My application need use the bundle jre in mac os system. I changed Info.plist below, tried to point to the jre, which I bundled from install4j. but when I run the application, the system still pop up a dialog to me. "To open 'serviceAgent' you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime". I have added the JVM attributers in Info.plist. Is there anything wrong about the Info.plist? Thanks so much. Tyki

```
<key>Java</key>
<dict>
<key>MainClass</key>
<string>com.tesst.service.ServiceManagerAgent</string>
<key>StartOnMainThread</key>
<true/>
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8+</string>
<key>JVMRuntime</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/../.install4j/jre.bundle</string>**
<key>ClassPath</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/../lib/spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar/string>
<key>Properties</key>
<dict>
<key>log4j.configuration</key>
<string>file:$APP_PACKAGE/../conf/log4j.properties</string>
</dict>
</dict>
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: You don't have to edit the Info.plist file to use a bundled JRE, that is done automatically. Java 6 and Java 7+ require different binary launchers on macOS. What install4j version do you use and what are your settings on the "JRE" step of the media wizard?

Comment: @IngoKegel Thanks for your reply. I need run my app when the macOS without the jdk/jre. so I need the app run with my jre. I use the install4j 5.1.15. On media wizard, I bundle the following JRE, Manual entry.

Comment: That version is too old, you would have to upgrade to the current version

Comment: yes, I know, but I just had the license for 5.x. Do you think we can use this version bundle the jre for my appliacation?

Comment: macOS has changed in several aspects during the last releases that are relevant for install4j. I doubt that 5.1 is suitable for the current release. I have the feeling that you have selected the Apple Java option on the "JRE" step of the media wizard.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. but I can't use the latest version of install4j. In the media wizard, I selected "Bundle the following JRE:" then selected the "Manual enrty" in the list, at last I filled the "${compiler:jre_dir}/jre_mac_1.8.0.152.tar.gz.". I think install4j packaged the jre which I selected. I can find the bundle jre from .install4j/jre.bundle.Do you think is it possible I can use it in the plist to run my application?

Comment: How did you create that .tar.gz file? This only works if the bundle was created by install4j and the JRE bundle creation wizard for macOS was only introduced in 6.0.

Comment: I changed my mind to fix this issue. I will use "Run executable or batch file" action to run the sh script. I will let the script start my appliction. I think this is a solution.